# SwiftUI PhotoPicker, get type of PhotoPickerItem

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am attempting to use SwiftUI's PhotoPicker to allow users to select and display both images and photos with a single PhotoPicker. I am able already to select images and videos and have been able to display only images, but I am struggling on how I am able to tell if a selected item is a video or an image. Is there an easy way to do this is am missing? Thanks for any help, here is my code currently which works to display images, but no the videos:

```
@State private var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
@State private var selectedImages: [Image] = []
public var body: some View {
    LazyVStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            HStack{
                ForEach(0..<selectedImages.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    selectedImages[i]
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                }
                PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItems) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square.fill").font(.title)
                }
            }.onChange(of: selectedItems) { _ in
                selectedImages.removeAll()
                Task {
                    for item in selectedItems {
                        if let data = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                                let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    selectedImages.append(image)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

If there is no way to explicitly tell the type of the item then I may use two PhotoPickers, but I will still need a way to display Videos that have been selected from a photoPicker as I am not sure how I will accomplish that yet either, so any help there is also appreciated

Comment: For clarity, do you want users to be able to select images and videos from the same picker or do you want them to be able to select only images?

Comment: I want to be able to select images and videos from one picker, I have updated the question to make it clearer, thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at `PhotosPickerItem`'s `supportedContentTypes`? You could check it like this `someUTType.isSubtype(of: .video)`. Don't forget `import UniformTypeIdentifiers.UTType`

Comment: You can use [PHPickerFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerfilter)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is that not for filtering what the user can select in the photo library? I don't need help with that, I just need to be able to tell what type of item they have selected after, does it offer a better solution for that too?

Comment: You are right, I misread what you wrote and thought you wanted to filter what the use can select from. I guess UTType is the way to go then.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to the comments I was able to come up with a working solution, so here it is:

```
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0..<selectedImages.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        selectedImages[i]
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    }
                    ForEach(selectedVideos, id: \.url) { video in
                        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: video.url))
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width:300, height: 300)
                    }
                    PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItems) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.square.fill").font(.title)
                    }
                }.onChange(of: selectedItems) { _ in
                    selectedImages.removeAll()
                    selectedVideos.removeAll()
                    Task {
                        for item in selectedItems {
                            if (item.supportedContentTypes.contains(where: { type in type.isSubtype(of: .audiovisualContent)})){
                                if let movie = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        selectedVideos.append(movie)
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if let data = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                                    if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                                        let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            selectedImages.append(image)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
```

So, I used the UTType and match to .audioVisulaContent, then I am able to display the video based on a method I found in [this link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-import-videos-using-photospicker)

This code still needs some tiding up to handle loading states and errors, but the idea works